# Customize gnome-panel in Openbox?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel, openbox

I'm running Gnome/Openbox and I was able to load gnome-panel, which is great, but for some reason I can't right-click on it (i can, but nothing happens) and I don't see any other way to customize my panels.

Any tips on how to get the panel configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press and hold the alt-key while right-clicking. Or sometimes you have to press super+alt instead. It's supposed to be only alt.

This is new in Gnome Panel 3. Similarly, to drag panel applets around, press alt and middle-click.

Comment: super+alt+right click seems to do it!